# JS return structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

What is the difference between {} and ( ) in JavaScript's return statement?

```
const fruits = [
  {
    name: "FaceBook",
    nickname: "FB",
  },
  {
    name: "Youtube",
    nickname: "YT",
  },
  {
    name: "AmazonWebService",
    nickname: "AWS",
  },
];
const count = fruits.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return { ...acc, [cur.nickname]: cur.name };  // What does {} of return mean here?
}, {});
```

Comment: returning a brand new `object` with spreading all the properties of `acc` and adding a new property with key as `cur.nickname` which is a computed value and a value as `cur.name`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `return` is not a `function`, but a `statement`, It is syntactically similar to other simple control flow statements like `break` and `continue` that don't use **parentheses** either.

So **parentheses** in `return` are just like **parentheses** anywhere else, its for order of calculations or just grouping.

But when you use **curly brackets** in `return` its for returning a new `object`, that's also applicable anywhere else.

In conclusion they have nothing to do with the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is a [literal object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) used to construct a new initialized object.

`()` is simple grouping of an expression.  `return ( ...acc, [cur.nickname]: cur.name )` would return the last expression `cur.name` as the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates left to right and return the last expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `{}`, it will return it as an object, so you need to add a key into it.

See this example below for more explanations:

```js
function test1() {
  return 'ok'
}

function test2() {
  return ('ok')
}

function test3() {
  return { message: 'ok' } // it won't accept: return {'ok'}
}

console.log(test1())
console.log(test2())
console.log(test3())
```

In your case, the `[cur.nickname]` is the key. And the `cur.name` is the value

Answer (score -1):

`return { ...acc, [cur.nickname]: cur.name };`
will return a new `Object`